# Using preprocessor to define pointers

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

In my program I allocate five NxN matricies using one allocation. Each segment of NxN `double`s is treated as a separate matrix. When I first wrote the code, I defined pointers to each matrix like this.

```
#define MAX_N 1024 // could be anything
double* matricies = aligned_alloc(32, 5 * MAX_N * MAX_N * sizeof(double));
double* MA = matricies;
double* MB = matricies + MAX_N * MAX_N;
double* MC1 = matricies + 2 * MAX_N * MAX_N;
double* MC2 = matricies + 3 * MAX_N * MAX_N;
double* MC3 = matricies + 4 * MAX_N * MAX_N;
```

After thinking about it for awhile, and due to the fact the offset of each matrix can be determined at compile time I wrote this code.

```
double* matricies = aligned_alloc(32, 5 * MAX_N * MAX_N * sizeof(double));

#define MA (matricies)
#define MB (matricies + MAX_N * MAX_N)
#define MC1 (matricies + 2 * MAX_N * MAX_N)
#define MC2 (matricies + 3 * MAX_N * MAX_N)
#define MC3 (matricies + 4 * MAX_N * MAX_N)
```

These identifiers are used as pointers in the rest of the program. My question is whether or not this is a good practice? I have the feeling that this will not scale because identifiers could collide with other text in the source code. You can of course `#undef` as needed, but it could get clunky.

Comment: What is the reason for "using one allocation" rather than the simpler and more obvious five allocations?

Comment: @RayButterworth I guess it's just a micro-optimization. One allocation takes less time than five.

Comment: As a general rule, putting code in macros is a terrible practice. All you're doing is hiding code behind a name that the next person who has to maintain your code will probably assume (incorrectly) is nothing more than a constant. When they've spent hours debugging your code and finally discover that your macro is more than just a constant, they will curse you. I promise you they will because I've cursed macros like this many, many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is primarily opinion based whether you will use one way or the other. The "defines" approach will save a little memory as you wont need the pointer variables. However, the compiler may optimize the variables out of the code so ... perhaps there isn't anything saved anyway. In my opinion the "defines" approach makes the code harder to understand and maintain so I would not use the defines.

The **important problem** with your code is however that it doesn't do what you say you want it to do. You say you want NxN matricies but your code does not allow us to use it like that. Example:

```
#define MAX_N 1024

int main(){
    double* matricies = aligned_alloc(32, 5 * MAX_N * MAX_N * sizeof(double));
    double* MA = matricies;
    double* MB = matricies + MAX_N * MAX_N;

    MA[0][3] = 42.1;          // error
    MB[2][1] = 123.8;         // error

    printf("%f\n", MA[0][3]); // error  
    printf("%f\n", MB[2][1]); // error  

    return 0;
}
```

This code result in compiler errors like:

```
main.cpp:12:10: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
     MA[0][3] = 42.1;
```

because `MA` is a pointer to a double. To access data using `MA[..][..]` you need a different type for `MA`. That could be "a pointer to an array of double". Like:

```
#define MAX_N 1024

int main(){
    void* matricies = aligned_alloc(32, 5 * MAX_N * MAX_N * sizeof(double));
    double (*MA)[MAX_N] = matricies;
    double (*MB)[MAX_N] = MA + MAX_N;


    MA[0][3] = 42.1;
    MB[2][1] = 123.8;

    printf("%f\n", MA[0][3]);  
    printf("%f\n", MB[2][1]);  

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles with no errors and the NxN matricies can be accessed as one will expect. Finally, it is IMO also easier to read and understand than your original "defines approach".

Comment: I didn’t know how to declare multidimensional arrays like that, makes perfect sense over the preprocessor thing

Comment: If you needed a pointer to the beginning of `MA`, would you prefer `MA[0]` or `&MA[0][0]`? They both work but from a readability standpoint which would you use?

Comment: @BradyDean Well, their value is the same but they are different types. So I would use the form that matches the type I needed.

Answer (score 1):

> whether or not this is a good practice?

`#define MC3 (matricies + 4 * MAX_N * MAX_N)` is not a good idea.  Code is hiding an unusual coding approach leads to higher maintenance costs.

---

Note a problem with `5 * MAX_N * MAX_N`.  It is done with `int` math yet array indexing and sizing is best done with `size_t` math.  The original code can  overflow when `MAX_N > 21000`  Recommend 1) leading multiplication with  `sizeof(double)` and 2) use `u` on size constants like `#define MAX_N 1024u`  3) don't do this macro trick

Comment: `1024UL`, surely?

Comment: @rici `UL` would be better than `U`. Even better would  be `((size_t)1024)`.  Too bad we cant do something like `1024z`.